# Minimizing the probability that two iid binomials RVs are equal

Tags: probability, optimization, binomial-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be iid with distribution $\text{Bin}(n,p)$. I would like to show $P(X=Y)$ is minimzed when $p=1/2$.

$$P(X=Y)=\sum_{i=0}^n P(X=i)P(Y=i)=(1-p)^{2 n} \, _2F_1\left(-n,-n;1;\frac{p^2}{(p-1)^2}\right)$$ ($_2F_1$ is the [Hypergeometric Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html))

I'm wondering how to show that such a complicated function is minimzed at $p=1/2$ or if there is an all-around simpler approach for this problem.

Comment: Very nice question.  If we let $f(p)=P(X=Y)$, it is clear that $f(p)=f(1-p)$, and the problem would be solved if one could show $f$ was convex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The characteristic function (CF) of $X-Y$ has a tractable form:
$$\begin{aligned}\varphi_{n,p}(a)&=E[e^{ia(X-Y)}]=\\
&=E[e^{iaX}]E[e^{-iaY}]=\\
&=[(q+pe^{ia})(q+pe^{-ia})]^n=\\
&=(q^2+2qp\cos(a)+p^2)^n=\\
&=(\varphi_{1,p}(a))^n\end{aligned}$$
where $q=1-p$.  We want to minimize (wrt $p$) the integral
$$P_{n,p}(X=Y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{(-\pi,\pi]}\varphi_{n,p}(a)da$$
It remains to argue that $\varphi_{n,1/2}\leq \varphi_{n,p}$. Indeed:
$$\varphi_{n,1/2}(a)=(\varphi_{1,1/2}(a))^n\leq (\varphi_{1,p}(a))^n=\varphi_{n,p}(a),\,a \in (-\pi,\pi]$$

Comment: Thanks for this! Why is the integral from $(-\pi, \pi]$ and not over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @user2757771 You're welcome. In this case, the CF is a [DTFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform)

Comment: Right, understood